# Replace the below n rows values of a specific column with the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1    col2
 1       D
 2       A
 3       H
 4       K
 5       G
 6       A
 7       K
 8       H
 9       B
10       S
```

Now if the col2 value is A then fill the next two rows(we can change the number) with A
So the result will look like,

```
df
col1    col2
 1       D
 2       A
 3       A
 4       A
 5       G
 6       A
 7       A
 8       A
 9       B
10       S
```

I can do this using for loop and comparing one with another. But the execution time will be more. So I am looking for some pandas shortcuts/pythonic way to do it efficiently.

Comment: Use the documented location facilities (index) with a "row slice".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with `limit=2`. FInally we use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) 
to complete the values ​​that are not A and are not within the limit.

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].eq('A')).ffill(limit=2).fillna(df['col2'])
```

**Output**

```
   col1 col2 new_col2
0     1    D        D
1     2    A        A
2     3    H        A
3     4    K        A
4     5    G        G
5     6    A        A
6     7    K        A
7     8    H        A
8     9    B        B
9    10    S        S
```

We can also use [`DataFrame.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

```
df.loc[df['col2'].eq('A').rolling(3, min_periods=0).max().astype(bool),'col2'] = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use `ffill` with `limit=2` and `fillna` back

```
df['new_col2'] = df.col2.where(df.col2.eq('A')).ffill(limit=2).fillna(df.col2)

Out[164]:
   col1 col2 new_col2
0     1    D        D
1     2    A        A
2     3    H        A
3     4    K        A
4     5    G        G
5     6    A        A
6     7    K        A
7     8    H        A
8     9    B        B
9    10    S        S
```